# How do I Improve T-SQL query performance for retrieving the most recent date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an `employee` table that contains the columns

```
employee_id, name, hire_date, termination_date, rehire_date, is_active
```

in SQL Server. I would like to retrieve the most recent date of hire, termination or rehire for each employee, but only if the employee is active.

The result should include the `employee_id`, `name`, and the most recent date. How can I achieve this with a single query?

I am able to do it using the below method:

```
SELECT 
    employee_id, name, MAX(date) as most_recent_date
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         employee_id, name, hire_date AS date 
     FROM 
         employee
     UNION
     SELECT 
         employee_id, name, termination_date 
     FROM 
         employee
     UNION
     SELECT 
         employee_id, name, rehire_date 
     FROM 
         employee) AS t
WHERE 
    employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id 
                    FROM employee 
                    WHERE is_active = 1)
GROUP BY 
    employee_id, name
```

This solution seems to work, but I am not sure if it's the most efficient way. I am also worried about the performance when the employee table is large.

Can anyone advise on a better and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this subquery in your `WHERE` clause?? Just use `WHERE is_active = 1` ..... done!

Comment: Changes `UNION`s to an unpivot will likely be an improvement, as it doesn't result in 3 scans of the table, nor an expensive `DISTINCT`. Also don't put the `WHERE` in a subquery, put it in the `WHERE` of the dataset you're going to unpivot.

Comment: If an employee is rehired, do they get the same employee_id?

Comment: Performance will depend, in part, on how the table is indexed. Since you haven't shared the DDL we can't tell if there are any indexes. The semantics of `is_active` are unclear. Are there employees who are `is_active = 1` and the most recent activity is termination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this.

```
SELECT employee_id, name, (SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES (hire_date), (termination_date),(rehire_date)) AS value(v))  as most_recent_date
                    FROM employee 
                    WHERE is_active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically only one of those dates would be not null and thus it is a simple group by:

```
select employee_id, name, 
    max(coalesce(hire_date, termination_date, rehire_date)) as most_recent_date
from Employee
where is_Active = 1
group by employee_id, name;
```

But since design seems to be flawed already (why not a single column for those dates, with another for the type), we can't be sure if it is logical you could use:

```
select employee_id, name max(case 
  when 
  coalesce(hire_date,'00010101') > coalesce(termination_date,'00010101') and 
  coalesce(hire_date,'00010101') > coalesce(rehire_date,'00010101') then hire_date
  when 
  coalesce(termination_date,'00010101') > coalesce(rehire_date,'00010101') then termination_date
  else
  coalesce(rehire_date,'00010101')
  end)
from Employee 
where is_Active = 1
group by employee_id;
```

or one of the variations in other replies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cheesy but I think it should work.

```
SELECT        employee_id, name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(hire_date) > MAX(termination_date) AND 
            MAX(hire_date) > MAX(rehire_date) THEN MAX(hire_date) 
        WHEN MAX(termination_date) > MAX(hire_date) AND 
            MAX(termination_date) > MAX(rehire_date) THEN MAX(termination_date) 
        WHEN MAX(rehire_date) > MAX(hire_date) AND 
            MAX(rehire_date) > MAX(termination_date) THEN MAX(rehire_date) 
    END AS date
FROM            employee
WHERE        (is_active = 1)
GROUP BY employee_id, name
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Database and SQL Server 2022 we can use [GREATEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest). It will be something like this:

```
SELECT employee_id, name, GREATEST(hire_date,termination_date,rehire_date ) 
FROM employee
WHERE is_Active = 1
```

if you are not abel to use this function, then the old way:

```
SELECT employee_id, name,
       CASE 
            WHEN hire_date > ISNULL(termination_date, '1900-01-01') AND hire_date > ISNULL(rehire_date , '1900-01-01') THEN hire_date
            WHEN termination_date > ISNULL(hire_date, '1900-01-01') AND termination_date > ISNULL(rehire_date , '1900-01-01') THEN termination_date
            WHEN rehire_date > ISNULL(hire_date, '1900-01-01') AND rehire_date > ISNULL(termination_date , '1900-01-01') THEN rehire_date
       END
FROM employee
WHERE is_Active = 1
```

and maybe better looking handle for NULLs..

In both cases, it should be better in terms of IO.